# How to get the price paid for Android In-app Billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

The Android [In-app Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) states

> "When the checkout process is complete, the service sends your application the purchase details, such as the order number, the order date and time, and **the price paid**."

However, it doesn't appear there is a parameter for price paid in the [PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_reference.html#footer).  Am I missing something?  Does anyone know how to get the total price of a purchase at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is probably out of sync with the current implementation. There is unfortunately no API to get the price of IAB items, and I the PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED JSON didn't include such a field last time I checked.